# Creating multiple bigquery table from multiple folders in google storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Cloud bucket with multiple folders, each containing CSVs.

I want to create eventually one BigQuery table, containing all the CSVs, but add a column stating the original folder. I thought to first create a BigQuery table for each such folder and then union them.

Is there a quick way to create multiple BigQuery tables, one for each subfolder under a Google Cloud bucket? Plus - if there's an easy way to automatically add the folder name as a new column - it could be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a blog post about this:

https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-lazy-data-loading-ddl-dml-partitions-and-half-a-trillion-wikipedia-pageviews-cd3eacd657b6

The trick is to create a federated query in BigQuery pointing to a glob of your files (`gs://bucket/folder/*`), which gives you the pseudo column `_FILE_NAME`:

```
SELECT *, _FILE_NAME fn 
FROM `fh-bigquery.views.wikipedia_views_gcs` 
LIMIT 10
```

[image]

Ta-da!

Comment: Hi, sorry to revive an old post. In order to do this, we have to create the federated query in a python script, right? Is there a way to create a federated query that points to the bucket without having to do a python script? I've looked up in documentation, but I only find on how to point to Cloud SQL (I'm just following the lazy-mantra of the medium post haha)