# Create google bigquery tables from google cloud storage buckets ; BQ table names contain the date corresponding to the GCS subdirectories

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I want to create google bigquery tables from google cloud storage buckets. I want to use Python to do these.
I have no problem to access BQ and GCS with python. It works fine. But I have trouble to create the right python code for what I want to do.

In the cloud storage, I have a bucket "bucket/data/" which contains sub-directories organized by date in the form date=year-month-day. These sub-directories contain csv.gz files. For example, the full name is "bucket/data/date=2023-04-21" for the day April 21, 2023, "bucket/data/date=2023-04-22" for the day April 22, 2023, ...

I want the bigquery table name contains the date corresponding to the subdirectories date.
For instance : GCS : bucket/data/date=2023-04-21 - BQ : sessions_202304021

I also need the bigquery table schema to be created automatically.

Below the python code I tried without success :

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "*********.json"
storage_client = storage.Client()
bq_client = bigquery.Client()
bucket_name = "bucket"
directory_path = "bucket/data/"
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix=directory_path)
for blob in blobs:
    if blob.name.endswith("/"):
        date = blob.name.split("=")[-1]
        table_name = f"sessions_{date}"
        table_ref = bq_client.dataset("xxxxxxxxxxx").table(sessions_)        
        csv_file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, blob.name, "xxxxxxxxx.csv.gz")        
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
            autodetect=True,
            source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
            skip_leading_rows=1,
            compression=bigquery.Compression.GZIP,
        )
        job = bq_client.load_table_from_uri(
            csv_file_path, table_ref, job_config=job_config
        )
        job.result()
        print(f"Table BigQuery créée: {table.table_id}")
```

########################
EDIT ########################

I've found a solution. See the code below.
Sometimes, I get some error messages, due to the schema autodetection.

Many thanks for your help.

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Initialiser les clients
storage_client = storage.Client()
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()

# Spécifier le nom du bucket et le préfixe du fichier
bucket_name = 'my_bucket'
prefix = 'sub1/sub2/data/date='

# Spécifier le nom du dataset
dataset_name = 'my-project.your_dataset'  # Remplacez par le nom de votre dataset

# Spécifier la plage de dates
start_date = datetime(2023, 5, 26)
end_date = datetime(2023, 5, 27)

# Parcourir chaque date dans la plage de dates
date = start_date
while date <= end_date:
    # Construire le préfixe du fichier pour la date actuelle
    date_prefix = prefix + date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    # Récupérer la liste des fichiers dans le bucket pour la date actuelle
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix=date_prefix)

    # Parcourir chaque fichier et charger les données dans BigQuery
    for blob in blobs:
        # Construire l'URI du fichier gs
        uri = f"gs://{bucket_name}/{blob.name}"

        # Construire le nom de la table pour la date actuelle
        table_name = 'sessions_' + date.strftime('%Y%m%d')

        # Créer un job de chargement de données
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
            source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
            skip_leading_rows=1,
            autodetect=True,
           #allow_quoted_newlines=True,
           #schema=[
           #     bigquery.SchemaField('site_id', 'INTEGER'),
           #     bigquery.SchemaField('visit_id', 'STRING'),
           #         ]   
        )

        # Charger les données à partir de l'URI du fichier gs
        load_job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri(
            uri, f"{dataset_name}.{table_name}", job_config=job_config
        )

        # Attendre la fin du job
        load_job.result()

    # Passer à la date suivante
    date += timedelta(days=1)

print("Les données ont été chargées avec succès.")
```

Comment: Is there any error message pertaining to the failed tables creations? Is your code tagged as completed or successful after execution but nothing actually happened? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a python script to achieve this, please follow the instructions listed in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage#create-external-table).

> ```
> from google.cloud import bigquery
>
> # Construct a BigQuery client object.
> client = bigquery.Client()
>
> # TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
> table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"
>
> # TODO(developer): Set the external source format of your table.
> # Note that the set of allowed values for external data sources is
> # different than the set used for loading data (see :class:`~google.cloud.bigquery.job.SourceFormat`).
> external_source_format = "AVRO"
>
> # TODO(developer): Set the source_uris to point to your data in Google Cloud
> source_uris = [
>     "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/federated-formats-reference-file-schema/a-twitter.avro",
>     "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/federated-formats-reference-file-schema/b-twitter.avro",
>     "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/federated-formats-reference-file-schema/c-twitter.avro",
> ]
>
> # Create ExternalConfig object with external source format
> external_config = bigquery.ExternalConfig(external_source_format)
> # Set source_uris that point to your data in Google Cloud
> external_config.source_uris = source_uris
>
> # TODO(developer) You have the option to set a reference_file_schema_uri, which points to
> # a reference file for the table schema
> reference_file_schema_uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/federated-formats-reference-file-schema/b-twitter.avro"
>
> external_config.reference_file_schema_uri = reference_file_schema_uri
>
> table = bigquery.Table(table_id)
> # Set the external data configuration of the table
> table.external_data_configuration = external_config
> table = client.create_table(table)  # Make an API request.
>
> print(
>     f"Created table with external source format {table.external_data_configuration.source_format}"
> )
> ```

A similar question was [posted here in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298176/creating-multiple-bigquery-table-from-multiple-folders-in-google-storage) way back in 2018, kindly review it as well for it can help you gain insights with your requirements.

Comment: Hi, I've found a solution. I posed the new code in an edited version of my answer.
Sometimes, I get some error messages, due to the schema autodetection but it works.
Many thanks for your help.